# Userfriendly way of handling config files in python?

Tags: python, configuration

I want to write a program that sends an e-mail to one or more specified recipients when a certain event occurs. For this I need the user to write the parameters for the mail server into a config. Possible values are for example: serveradress, ports, ssl(true/false) and a list of desired recipients.

Whats the user-friendliest/best-practice way to do this?

I could of course use a python file with the correct parameters and the user has to fill it out, but I wouldn't consider this user friendly. I also read about the 'config' module in python, but it seems to me that it's made for creating config files on its own, and not to have users fill the files out themselves.

Comment: You should check http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html

Comment: I don't understand. The user will have to write parameters each time an email will be sent ? Why in this case to record the parameters in a config file ? Wouldn't the data contained in a string created with the parameters given by the user be sufficient ?

Comment: @eyquem The user should enter the data once in the config file. After that, the program always reads it from the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you saying that the fact that the config file would need to be valid Python makes it unfriendly? It seems like having lines in a file like:

```
 server = 'mail.domain.com'
 port = 25
```

...etc would be intuitive enough while still being valid Python. If you don't want the user to have to know that they have to quote strings, though, you might go the YAML route. I use YAML pretty much exclusively for config files and find it very intuitive, and it would also be intuitive for an end user I think (though it requires a third-party module - [PyYAML](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation)):

```
 server: mail.domain.com
 port: 25
```

Having pyyaml load it is simple:

```
>>> import yaml
>>> yaml.load("""a: 1
... b: foo
... """)
{'a': 1, 'b': 'foo'}
```

With a file it's easy too.

```
>>> with open('myconfig.yaml', 'r') as cfile:
...    config = yaml.load(cfile)
...
```

config now contains all of the parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I fear that python might not be user friendly because of the need to quote strings (as you mentioned) and because of indendation.
Yaml sounds great, there even is a python-yaml package for it in ubuntu.

Comment: yaml is really great, I use it a lot configuration files

Comment: @Basil: Most folks can find "quote" keys and match 'apostrophes' without difficulty.  For English users, it's standard, and they all know how to do it.  Are your users not English literate?

Comment: @S.Lott I didn't want to implie that the users would not be able to understand it. It's just that not having to care about quoting and indendtation makes it easier.

Comment: @Basil: For a configuration file, there should **never** be any indentation and only the simplest of quoting rules.  You'll find that the relevant subset of Python is often **much simpler** than all other syntax choices.

Comment: @S.Lott can you explain how not having to care about quoting or indentation is less optimal from an end user perspective than having to care?

Comment: @S.Lott "For a configuration file, there should never be any indentation and only the simplest of quoting rules." I agree.
In this case the user does not have to worry about quoting and I can learn something new.

Comment: @jonesy: Many, many configuration formats impose some syntax.  YAML has few, but not zero rules.  Common YAML syntax mistakes (like common Python syntax mistakes) lead to confusing errors.  Your opening suggestion (Python is good enough) is the point I want to emphasize.  Python's syntax is generally just as easy to use as any other.  In most cases easier.

Comment: @S.Lott - I guess I do make a few assumptions when suggesting yaml: a) the use case is pretty simplistic (as described) b) the end users are relatively or totally un-technical, c) the config isn't a moving target. In all, I agree that Python should typically be good enough. When it's not, I find YAML to be the least restrictive & also the most powerful option.

Answer (score 2):

I doesn't matter technically proficient your users are; you can count on them to screw up editing a text file.  (They'll save it in the wrong place. They'll use MS Word to edit a text file.  They'll make typos.)  I suggest making a gui that validates the input and creates the configuration file in the correct format and location.  A simple gui created in Tkinter would probably fit your needs.

Comment: I agree with you. But for the moment the program is command-line only, and it will stay like this for a while.

Comment: You can still make a program that asks for config options and saves them correctly using `raw_input`.  If you must have your users edit the file directly I would go with joesy's `yaml` answer.

Answer (score 1):

What are the drawbacks of such a solution:

```
ch = 'serveradress = %s\nport = %s\nssl = %s'

a = raw_input("Enter the server's address : ")

b = 'a'
bla = "\nEnter the port : "
while not all(x.isdigit() for x in b):
    b = raw_input(bla)
    bla = "Take care: you must enter digits exclusively\n"\
          +"  Re-enter the port (digits only) : "

c = ''
bla = "\nChoose the ssl option (t or f) : "
while c not in ('t','f'):
    c = raw_input(bla)
    bla = "Take care: you must type f or t exclusively\n"\
          +"  Re-choose the ssl option : "


with open('configfile.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(ch % (a,b,c))
```

.

PS

I've read in the jonesy's post that the value in a config file may have to be quoted. If so, and you want the user not to have to write him/her-self the quotes, you simply add

```
a = a.join('""')
b = b.join('""')
c = c.join('""')
```

.

### EDIT

```
ch = 'serveradress = %s\nport = %s\nssl = %s'

d = {0:('',
        "Enter the server's address : "),
     1:("Take care: you must enter digits exclusively",
        "Enter the port : "),
     2:("Take care: you must type f or t exclusively",
        "Choose the ssl option (t or f) : ")  }

def func(i,x):
    if x is None:
        return False
    if i==0:
        return True
    elif i==1:
        try:
            ess = int(x)
            return True
        except:
            return False
    elif i==2:
        if x in ('t','f'):
            return True
        else:
            return False


li = len(d)*[None]
L = range(len(d))

while True:

    for n in sorted(L):
        bla = d[n][1]
        val = None
        while not func(n,val):
            val = raw_input(bla)
            bla = '\n  '.join(d[n])
        li[n] = val.join('""')

    decision = ''
    disp = "\n====== If you choose to process, =============="\
           +"\n    the content of the file will be :\n\n" \
           + ch % tuple(li) \
           + "\n==============================================="\
           + "\n\nDo you want to process (type y) or to correct (type c) : "
    while decision not in ('y','c'):
        decision = raw_input(disp)
        disp = "Do you want to process (type y) or to correct (type c) ? : "

    if decision=='y':
        break
    else:
        diag = False
        while not diag:
            vi = '\nWhat lines do you want to correct ?\n'\
                 +'\n'.join(str(j)+' - '+line for j,line in enumerate((ch % tuple(li)).splitlines()))\
                 +'\nType numbers of lines belonging to range(0,'+str(len(d))+') separated by spaces) :\n'
            to_modify = raw_input(vi)
            try:
                diag = all(int(entry) in xrange(len(d)) for entry in to_modify.split())
                L = [int(entry) for entry in to_modify.split()]
            except:
                diag = False


with open('configfile.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(ch % tuple(li))

print '-*-  Recording of the config file : done  -*-'
```

Comment: I think in general it's a good idea. The only problem I see with this, is that if you make a typo, you have to enter the whole thing again. But I think I'll add comments like your ("..you must enter digits exclusively") to the file.

Comment: @Basil Well, it can be corrected. Let me a little time and I will propose you an improvement.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html). It's designed to read **.ini** style files that have:

```
[section]
option = value
```

It's quite easy to use and the documentation is pretty easy to read. Basically you just load the whole file into a ConfigParser object:

```
import ConfigParser    

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read('configfile.txt')
```

Then you can make sure the users haven't messed anything up by checking the options. I do so with a list:

```
OPTIONS = 
    ['section,option,defaultvalue',
     .
     .
     .
    ]

for opt in OPTIONS:
    section,option,defaultval = opt.split(',')
    if not config.has_option(section,option):
        print "Missing option %s in section %s" % (option,section)
```

Getting the values out is easy too.

```
val = config.get('section','option')
```

And I also wrote a function that creates a sample config file using that **OPTIONS** list.

```
    new_config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    for opt in OPTIONS:
        section,option,defaultval = opt.split(',')
        if not new_config.has_section(section):
            new_config.add_section(section)
        new_config.set(section, option, defaultval)
    with open("sample_configfile.txt", 'wb') as newconfigfile:
        new_config.write(newconfigfile)
    print "Generated file: sample_configfile.txt"
```